# Concatenate lists together

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the value elements are lists:

```
d1={'A': [], 'C': ['SUV'], 'B': []}
```

I need to concatenate the values into a single list ,only if the list is non-empty.
Expected output:

```
o=['SUV']
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
d1={'A': [], 'C': ['SUV'], 'B': []}
print list(chain.from_iterable(d1.itervalues()))
```

Comment: This answer is better than Ashwin's because it fully utilizes the fact that chain can deal with iterators and not just eagerly generated sequences.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.chain`, but the order can be  arbitrary as dicts are unordered collection. So may have have to sort the dict based on keys or values to get the desired result.

```
>>> d1={'A': [], 'C': ['SUV'], 'B': []}
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*d1.values())) # or use d1.itervalues() as it returns an iterator(memory efficient)
['SUV']
```

Comment: Please use `chain.from_iterable` for these jobs

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> d1 = {'A': [], 'C': ['SUV'], 'B': []}
>>> [ele for lst in d1.itervalues() for ele in lst]
['SUV']
```

Comment: +1; I like this solution though I would replace `values` by `itervalues`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> d1={'A': [], 'C': ['SUV'], 'B': []}
>>> reduce(add,d1.itervalues())
['SUV']
```

Or more comprehensive example:

```
>>> d2={'A': ["I","Don't","Drive"], 'C': ['SUV'], 'B': ["Boy"]}
>>> reduce(add,d2.itervalues())
['I', "Don't", 'Drive', 'SUV', 'Boy']
```

Comment: unfortunately this has O(N^2) behavior since you are creating a new list on each `add`

Comment: @jamylak True, this is a horribly inefficient approach (just had to put a functional approach out there)

Comment: what about ```sum(d2.itervalues(), [])```

Comment: `f = []`, `map(f.extend,d2.itervalues())` is also another poor method of solving it

Comment: @HennyH the other approaches are still functional, but I see what you mean